# How to make a function that makes a picturebox not detect another picturebox's boundaries (which are transparent), and detect the picture itself?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, picturebox

How to make a function that makes a picturebox not detect another picturebox's boundaries (which are transparent), and detect the picture itself? is there another way to detect the collision of a picturebox other than `picturebox1.Bounds`? here's my code:

```
if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox3.Bounds)
{
//some code here
}
```

picturebox2 is a full picture, and it doesn't have any transparency, but picturbox3 has a transparent background, the if statement gets triggered when picturebox2 touches the transparent part of picturebox3, can anyone help me avoid that?

Comment: This depends on the [SizeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of your [PictureBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and the size of your picture.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to use `PictureBox` controls? To render overlapped images or sprites you can directly paint the bitmaps in the `Paint` event of the parent panel or form, which is much faster. Anyway, testing the bounding rectangles is the first step. If they intersect you should perform an additional [per-pixel collision test](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2134/Collision-A-Csharp-Game-Part-3-Pixel-Perfect-Colli)

Comment: normal visual studio winforms UI

Comment: what do you mean Olivier Jacot-Descombes, what should i do to fix this?

Comment: If the image itself is not transparent and rectangular, then you can calculate its display size based on the the SizeMode and put this calculated size and position into a Rectangle and use that one for intersection testing.

Comment: the problem is, Olivier Jacot-Descombes, its a triangle, so i cant do what you are telling me to do